# How to get list of all static members of some class in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, static

I would like to get list of all static members of some class. For example: I would like to get all static members of `Object` (like `Object.create` if avalible and so on). How can I do that?

Example:

```
var ClassA = function(){}
ClassA.prototype.getName = function(){return "ClassA";} //public method
ClassA.alertName = function(){ alert("ClassA");} //static method
ClassA.doSomething = function(){return "Do something";} //another static method
```

So, if I got more static members, I would like to get at least names of them. In this example I would like to get `alertName` and `doSomething`. With public members you can do something like that:

```
for (i in ClassA.prototype) {
    alert(i);
}
```

How about with static members?

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys **or** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames (depending on what you want)

Comment: sorry for that. You can get public members with something like this: for(var i in obj){alert(i + " : " + obj[i]);} but it is different with  classes. I will check your suggestion, but I  see problem with browser compatibilities (supports only ie9 for example)

Comment: So try to explain more what you mean by "static members". What do you mean "but it is different with classes"? `Object.keys` has a polyfill that you can insert to include compatibility for older browsers (scroll down to the "Compatibility" section). The `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` is a little different, so I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for anyways.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're trying to get a list of all static members of some class?

Comment: @AleksanderFras: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make a note of the formatting improvements that have been made to your post; documentation on the formatting options on Stack Overflow can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: just to comfirm it: yes:) Good one:)

Comment: @Ian "what you mean by "static members"."  The term `static` is actually very well defined for Ecmascript and it means exactly what he shows in his example. ES6 even introduces a new keyword `static` to allow you to write static members inside your class definition (without that keyword you would have to add them later like in the example). Meanwhile your `new record` comment gets 4 upvotes while the question itself gets none, even though it's a **very good question**.

Comment: @StijndeWitt Please take a look at both the question's creation time (as well as my comments')...this was just about 3 years ago, before ES6 was really a thing. So looking in the ES5 specification, the only mention of the word "static" is as a future reserved word. Can you explain what your point is? And why you're complaining about a misunderstanding of mine, 3 years ago?

Comment: Static was already well defined for Javascript 3 years ago. There is a reason it was a reserved word already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How are you trying to inspect them?

Why can't you just use the same iterator to go through your actual class?

```
var key = "";
for (key in MyClass) { console.log(key); }
```

This isn't your every-day language.
Practically everything in JS is an object, including functions/constructor functions.

As such, what seems like "public static" to you, here, is actually just a method of an object, which can be iterated through, like any other object.

Also: prototyping IS public static.
If you prototype a property into your instances, then all instances have a reference to that exact same property, and modifications of that property will change the reference for everyone else.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about that. It is bothering me, why can't I also get results for Object this way (Object.create for example...) But there should exist something like Object.create if typeof it is not "undefined".

Comment: Because it's a native object and it's locked down with hidden properties which were never exposed to end-users until ECMAScript5.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
Object.keys(MyClass);
```

This will give you every static property of whatever you want. Also, you don't need to check for inherited properties.